# NFS Common Utilities fails to start

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, nfs, portmap

I created a virtual machine and installed Debian 6 on it, and then copied the hard drive to be used by another virtual machine. For the newly copied virtual machine, I changed the IP address, hostname and MAC address. Now, whenever I start up the machine, it comes up with these failure messages:
"Starting NFS Common Utilities: statd failed!"
"startpar: service(s) returned failure: nfs-common ... failed!"
"ALERT: exim paniclog /var/log/exim4/paniclog has -non-zero size, mail system possibly broken ... failed!"

I know this is a rather common issue but I haven't yet found any answers to the problem. I've already tried uninstalling nfs-common and portmap, then re-installing nfs-common and rpcbind (I read that I should install that instead of portmap). This did not wield success. Could someone please tell me what steps I can take to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `man statd`
2. `/FILES`
3. Start reading.

First guess: you still have the old hostname floating around in a couple of configuration files.
I'd check for that first:

1. `find /etc /var -type f | xargs fgrep` *(whatever your old hostname was)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried typing in that second command and was greeted with a lot of log files containing that old hostname. I also read the statd man file, but couldn't see how that would help.... Sorry. Could you maybe tell me how I can sift through all the log files and see only the config files? Thanks!

Comment: Please disregard previous comment if it is still displaying. I tried deleting it, but it wouldn't delete.

Comment: What did you try to delete??  Yes, logs are usually in `/var/log` so you may want to replace `/var` with something more specific.  Please don't type in commands or delete files without understanding what they do - they all have documentation, e.g. `man find` gives you the explanation for the `find` command.

Comment: I tried to delete my previous comment as I had resolved the issue. Thanks for your help and sorry for my slow response!

Comment: Never mind ... good to know that your issue is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Any logs of nfs and portmap? syslog, dmesg?
Also you can add `set -x` in the beginning of init script and run it manually, to see when and why it fails.

Comment: I tried set -x but that didn't do anything. However, I did try bash -x but that just bombarded me with bits of code such as "NEED_GSSD=no" and "log_progress_msg statd". How do I access the logs for NFS? And for portmap?

Comment: run `dpkg-query -L <package>` to see, if there are log files for that package in /var/log. If no, then all messages are logged to syslog, which by default in Debian and Ubuntu resides in /var/log/syslog. Run `tailf /var/log/syslog`, restart statd, portmap, see what messages do appear. Also you can change service start options in `/etc/default/<service name>`, according to it's manpage, to achieve more verbose debugging output